# ¿How to use complex html with Daisy UI Tooltip?

Tags: html, frontend, tooltip, tailwind-css

Example:

```
<div class="tooltip" data-tip="hi<br>hi" data-html="true">
    ...
</div>
```

This output in tooltip:

```
hi<br>hi
```

How can i get this output:

```
hi
hi
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, Daisy UI tooltip is limited. But, I think you can play with the CSS selector ".tooltip: before" to achieve what you need.

To solve your problem:

- use 
   i.e hi 
  hi
- add these classes - 'before:whitespace-pre', 'before:content-[attr(data-tip)]'

  ...